# htaccess redirection - stop redirecting subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/de/(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1
```

My problem is that it redirects even http://xyz.example.com/de/ to http://de.example.com/

What I need is still redirecting from example.com/de to de.example.com
but without redirecting xyz.example.com/de to de.example.com

Could you help me to modify that?

Answer (score 0):

You ar mixing directives from 2 different Apache modules `mod_rewrite` and `mod_alias`. Stick to `mod_rewrite` only and have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still redirects http://xyz.example.com/de to http://de.example.com. I would like to exclude the subdomain xyz from this redirection.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about use of `RewriteRule`. Try my updated rule now.